# Javascript on different types of Loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6

It's a question on conditionals. Now, I searched and see a different(correct) way to do it. But I just don't understand why my way is not working.:

question: Write a function called "getLongestOfThreeWords".

Given 3 words, "getLongestOfThreeWords" returns the longest of three words.

Notes:

If there is a tie, it should return the first word in the tie.

I understand the 'correct' way but my answer shows 'undefined' and cant seem to figure out why..

```
"My way"    

function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
if(word1.length > word2.length  && word1.length > word3.length){
    return word1;
} else if(word2.length > word1.length && word2.length > word3.length){
    return word2;
} else if (word3.length > word1.length && word3.length > word2.length){
    return word3;
} 
}
```

vs

```
"correct way"

function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  let wordsArr = [word1, word2, word3];
  let longestWord = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < wordsArr.length; i++) {
    if (wordsArr[i].length > longestWord.length) {
      longestWord = wordsArr[i];
    } 
  }
  return longestWord;
}
var output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output); // --> 'these'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't adjusted for edge cases - when there are two words that are the same length and that length is larger than the other word. (Also note that your way is quite inefficient and requires a lot of adjustment for even one more word) Try this:

```
if (...) {...}
else if (...) {...}
else if (...) {...}
else if (word1.length == word2.length && word1.length > word3.length) {
    return word1;
}
else if (word2.length == word3.length && word2.length > word1.length) {
    return word3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
    if(word1.length >= word2.length  && word1.length >= word3.length){
        return word1;
    } else if(word2.length >= word1.length && word2.length >= word3.length){
        return word2;
    } else if (word3.length >= word1.length && word3.length >= word2.length){
        return word3;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLongestOfThreeWords(word1, word2, word3) {
  
  var newArr = [word1, word2, word3];
  
  
  //variable for longest string and array for elements to 
  //be pushed to that meet conditions
  var longWord = newArr[0].length;
  var doubleArr = [];

  //iterate,
  for(var i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
    //if element length is longer than longWord,
    if(newArr[i].length > longWord) {
      //replace longWord,
      longWord = newArr[i].length;
      doubleArr = [];
        //push element into doubleArr.
        doubleArr.push(newArr[i]);
    } else {
      //edge case if there is more than one word tied for longest.
      if(newArr[i].length === longWord){
        //places that word in the next index.
        doubleArr.push(newArr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  //return the first element that met the longest condition.
  return doubleArr[0];
}
var output = getLongestOfThreeWords('these', 'three', 'words');
console.log(output); // --> 'these'
```